# pygame: full image support images

Tags: python, pygame

I want to use .png images in pygame but it requires full image support. How do I do this?

Also, what are some image formats that I can use in pygame that doesn't need full image support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pygame documentation for images explicitly says

The image module is a required dependency of Pygame, but it only optionally supports any extended file formats. By default it can only load uncompressed BMP images.

So, I suppose you should run

```
pygame.image.get_extended() # returns a bool
```

to check if you can load images of other extensions. If not, I suppose you will need Python imaging libraries to be installed to get extended file formats to be supported by Pygame.

OR, you could always convert the images to BMP to avoid the hassle.

Comment: Lots of online converter